# React Native Dropdown

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to write a mobile app using local response. How can I add a drop-down like the one shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work, and what was expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

**react-native-popup-menu**

It's a good library which provides dropDown options as a Menu.

Comment: Thank you. 
I guess that's what I'm looking for.